# Glassfish Server not shown in Netbeans 6.0.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

[image]

I have installed Netbeans 6.0.1 as it supports SOAP protocol which is not supported by versions above 6. So, After installing Netbeans(for Java EE) when I try to create a new project the glassfish server which is installed is not being shown in the server list.

Please help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: Which glassfish version do you use?

Comment: It's GlassFish-v2ur1. The default server that gets installed when we install Netbeans 6.0.1 for Java EE

Answer (score 3):

You haven't actually registered the GlassFish server in Netbeans. In other words, you may well have installed GlassFish, but Netbeans doesn't know anything about it. To fix that, you need to follow the instructions in red and click the button that says "Add..." to add your installed GlassFish to Netbeans.

I should also point out that Netbeans 6 and GlassFish 2 (Java EE 5!) are both incredibly old and out-of-date. There is no reason for you to use such old versions since web services with SOAP are still supported in GlassFish 5 (Java EE 8) and Netbeans 8.2

For example, the official Java EE 8 tutorial includes a section on JAX-WS, the API which is used to create SOAP webservices, in chapter 31:
https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html

The [overview for section 31](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxws001.html#A1250966) states:

> ***Overview of Java API for XML Web Services***
>   In JAX-WS, a web service operation invocation is represented by an XML-based protocol,
>   such as SOAP. The SOAP specification defines the envelope structure,
>   encoding rules, and conventions for representing web service
>   invocations and responses. These calls and responses are transmitted
>   as SOAP messages (XML files) over HTTP.
>
> Although SOAP messages are complex, the JAX-WS API hides this
>   complexity from the application developer. On the server side, the
>   developer specifies the web service operations by defining methods in
>   an interface written in the Java programming language. The developer
>   also codes one or more classes that implement those methods. Client
>   programs are also easy to code. A client creates a proxy (a local
>   object representing the service) and then simply invokes methods on
>   the proxy. With JAX-WS, the developer does not generate or parse SOAP
>   messages. It is the JAX-WS runtime system that converts the API calls
>   and responses to and from SOAP messages.
>
> With JAX-WS, clients and web services have a big advantage: the
>   platform independence of the Java programming language. In addition,
>   JAX-WS is not restrictive: A JAX-WS client can access a web service
>   that is not running on the Java platform and vice versa. This
>   flexibility is possible because JAX-WS uses technologies defined by
>   the W3C: HTTP, SOAP, and WSDL. WSDL specifies an XML format for
>   describing a service as a set of endpoints operating on messages.

I would highly recommend you use version 8.2 of Netbeans with version 5 of GlassFish, since you are currently trying to use software which is 12 years old!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the version of glassfish you are using, but you can try two things that might work:

1. Try installing glassfish 3, this should be compatible
   Or:
2. Let netbeans install the glassfish server

I hope I could help you.